# Why is $m_{\ell}$ called the magnetic quantum number? What is its association with magnets?

Tags: atomic-physics, terminology, orbitals, magnetic-moment

I am going over my quantum lecture notes and I can't seem to link the quantum number $m_{\ell}$ with any magnetic property. It just seems to specify the shape of an orbital with a particular principal quantum number. Is there any reason for it being labelled as magnetic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An angular momentum of an electron about a nucleus of $\bf L$ implies a magnetic moment $-\mu_B \bf L$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_magnetic_moment#Orbital_magnetic_dipole_moment).

Answer (score 2):

The magnetic quantum number $m_\ell$ determines the energy shift
when the atom is in an external magnetic field.

Quoted from [Magnetic quantum number - Effect in magnetic fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_quantum_number#Effect_in_magnetic_fields):

> The quantum number $m$ refers, loosely, to the direction of the angular
>    momentum vector. The magnetic quantum number $m$ only affects the electron's
>    energy if it is in a magnetic field because in the absence of one,
>    all spherical harmonics corresponding to the different arbitrary values
>    of $m$ are equivalent. The magnetic quantum number determines the energy
>    shift of an atomic orbital due to an external magnetic field (the Zeeman
>    effect) — hence the name magnetic quantum number.

Answer (score 0):

The  wikipedia page linked in my2cts's answer says:

> The revolution of an electron around an axis through another object, such as the nucleus, gives rise to the orbital magnetic dipole moment.

I would say that such  a statement is not fully  consistent with a truly quantum-mechanical description (did they wrote revolution?), or, at the least it would require a few additional words for its justification. Here they are.

States with non-zero magnetic quantum number correspond to complex wavefunctions such that the quantum probability current density 
$$
{\bf j}({\bf r})=\frac{1}{2m}\left(  \Psi^* {\bf \hat p} \Psi - \Psi {\bf \hat p} \Psi^* \right),
$$
is different from zero as well as  the resulting electric current density and magnetic moment
$$
{\bf m}=\frac{e}{2}\int {\bf r}\times {\bf j}({\bf r}) d^{3}{\bf r},
$$
where $e$ is the electron charge.

By performing the integral in the case of the hydrogen atom wavefunctions, one can check the proportionality between magnetic moment and angular momentum via the Bohr's magneton ($\mu_B$).